# dealing with sliding in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have this script that with li list, if you click on one of the list items, a box slides to the right, and if you click again, its slides back to its orginal place(toggle)

the demo is here:

http://www.kornar.co.uk/home2.php

the problem that i have is on slideout, i want the width of the panel to be 700px

```
$(".panel").css("width","700px");
```

on slide back in, i want the width to be 350px, so it hides behind the list again.

```
$(".panel").css("width","350px");
```

but the problem im having is on when it slides back, it deosnt hide behind the list, it still shows the panel on the right? thanks

Comment: Just a small suggestion, just for readability - you may want to format the code with tabs. A lot of applications have this built in. For example in Visual Web Developer it is Edit > Format Document. This will do the majority of it; the rest is down to the developer (for example whether you prefer opening braces on the same line as the function name or the beginning of the following line).

Comment: yeh defo, sorry about that, i was just testing this jquery thing out, sfor my client, i will get to that afetr i solve this problem! :)) thanks again

Comment: no problem... glad to help. Now back to the problem at hand!! :)

Comment: lool thank you, all i want to to really, is to slide in and slide out thats it, when it slides out its 700px, and when it slides in 350px. im so stupid!! lol

Comment: you're not stupid - it takes time to learn these things and at the end of the day, noone is perfect and everyone makes mistakes (sometimes they are stupid mistakes like typos).

Comment: and also when you select an element into a variable, you don't need to select it all the time after, like Here `var panel= $('.panel');
    //the problem
     $(".panel").css("width","350px");
`

Comment: I think I see the problem... in the animate bits, if you set the html of an element to the css("left") of the panel (after the animation) then you will see that it is "0px" - a string, not an integer. So converting panel.css("left") to an integer will result in an error. Not entirely sure if this is causing the issue though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hey dude, I made a couple of assumptions about what you were trying achieve on the whole, but maybe this is what you were trying to do... The following is all I changed:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

      $('.block').click(function(){
        var id= $(this).attr('id');
        var data_id= $(".data").html();
        var panelPositionLeft=$('.panel').css('left');

        if(panelPositionLeft=='0px') {
          //the .panel is hidden, so slide it out and populate .data with the new id
          $('.panel').animate({left: 350, width:700});
          $('.data').html(id);
        } else if (data_id!=id){
          //something other than the previous .block was clicked and the .panel is obviously open, so don't collapse, just add the new id into .data
          $('.data').html(id);
        } else {
          //neither of the previous situations are true, so it must be that the previously clicked block is being clicked again. Just slide it closed and don't change the value of .data
          $('.panel').animate({left: 0, width: 350});       
        }
      });


      $('.close').click(function(){
        // just slide it closed.
        $('.panel').animate({left: 0, width: 350});
      });

    });

    </script>
```

There are still a few things you could clean up, but I thought this would be a little easier to read and understand. Try this out, let me know if I misunderstood the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: damn you... I was this close (distance between thumb and first finger being about 5mm) to getting to near enough the same solution!! :)

Comment: @getaway: NP, hope that helps.
@ClarkeyBoy: haha sorry, bro. Post it anyway, so we can all compare notes ;D

Comment: Please note that there is still some of the panel showing underneath - it wasn't mentioned in the question so thought I should mention it.

Comment: @Masondesu: Nah its alright - mine would've been a slightly longer way than yours, but achieved the same result. Yours is more efficient by way of the amount of code (not sure about the amount of processing - but who cares about that when it takes such a short time in any case).

Comment: can i ask you, if i wanted to load an iframe, when click on the list item, is that possible? if you get what i mean

Comment: its not quite there, but I will be there soon. I kinda gave up thinking its pointless to compare it since your solution is better... give me a few minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Try surrounding the "+" with quotes (i.e. "+" + panel.outerWidth()). I think this should work.

Richard

Comment: Ah yeah you're right - no effect what so ever!! Am just working on it atm.

Answer (score 1):

For getaways reference: this is what I would have posted had masondesu not got there first. As you can see it is very similar, but has if statements where none are actually required (as in masondesu's solution.

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.block').click(function () {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            var data_id = $(".data").html();
            var panel = $('.panel');
            var panel_width = $('.panel').css('left');
            var currLeft = panel.css('left');
            var blockWidth = $(".left").outerWidth();
            if (data_id == id) {
                if (currLeft == "0px") {
                    panel.animate({ left: blockWidth, width: "700px" });
                } else {
                    panel.animate({ left: "0px", width: "350px" });
                }
            }
            else {
                if (currLeft == "0px") {
                    panel.animate({ left: blockWidth, width: "700px" });
                } else {
                    panel.animate({ left: "0px", width: "350px" });
                }
            }
            $('.data').html(id);
            return false;
        });
        $('.close').click(function () {
            var panel = $('.panel');
            var currLeft = panel.css('left');
            if (currLeft == "0px") {
                panel.animate({ left: blockWidth, width: "700px" });
            } else {
                panel.animate({ left: "0px", width: "350px" });
            }
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Regards,

Richard

Comment: I have noticed a couple of minor errors in this. It will do what you want, but there are a couple of bits I have left in which can be removed. Firstly I have said `if (panel.css("left") ...) {`. This can be changed to `if (currLeft ...) {`. Secondly the bits that say `left: currLeft == "0px" ? blockWidth : "0px"` can be altered since they are within if / else statements for that condition in any case. Will alter it to account for this in a moment.

Answer (score 0):

You don't resize the panel on "li"-click, it resizes only on ".close"-click. so it won't resize ;)

Comment: it resizes through `$('.block').click()` too, not just `$('.close').click()`. I don't think this is the problem.